# How to avoid selenium block?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, navigation, recaptcha

I'm trying to create a script to automatically login to [this](https://prenotami.esteri.it)  site with selenium. But inevitably it always redirects to an "unavailable" page. I already read many threads regarding selenium blocking and tried with different browsers, but still the problem. Also i'm trying with proxy servers and diferents os. Here is my code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)

options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver', options=options)

driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

driver.get('https://prenotami.esteri.it')

try:

    email = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login-email")))
    email.click()
    correo = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
    for c in correo:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        email.send_keys(c)
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login-password")))
    password.click()
    clave = 'Dxxxx2023'
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 700)')
    for c in clave:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        password.send_keys(c)
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 700)')
    time.sleep(1)
    boton_avanti = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div/section[1]/form/button")
    boton_avanti.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)



finally:
    time.sleep(5)

input("waiting")
driver.quit()
```

I have even tried with uc_chromedriver and with different browsers.
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://github.com/diprajpatra/selenium-stealth. Try different settings, if the site really has protection against bots, then this can help.

For chrome explicitly: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

Comment: thanks, but nothing change. Even in the same browser that opens selenium, I enter the data manually and it enters correctly.